# How to write custom output attribute aggregator function for WSO2CEP 3.0.0

Tags: wso2

By following the documentation on [Writing a Custom Output Attribute Aggregator](http://docs.wso2.org/display/CEP300/Writing+a+Custom+OutputAttributeAggregator), one can not decide how to implement the functions `processAdd` or `processRemove`. Could someone help me understand what duties of these functions are?

Besides, although implemented, `newInstance` function is not used in the sample provided. What is the purpose of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`processAdd` and `processRemove` are called when an event is added and removed respectively from a query processor state. Siddhi engine wraps an event in a class that implements `org.wso2.siddhi.core.event.remove.RemoveStream` when removing an event from the query processor state. Similarly, implementations of `org.wso2.siddhi.core.event.in.InStream` can be used to identify new events.

Based on this, you can identify if an event is being added/removed for queries that keep state (like in windows, sequences, patterns etc.). Calling methods in this manner allows you to do certain computations optimally with minimum performance impact (e.g. when calculating average, you can just add to an already available total and divide without iterating through the whole list of events that need to be considered).

You can go through the code of [AvgOutputAttributeAggregatorDouble](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/dependencies/commons/siddhi/2.1.0-wso2v1/modules/siddhi-core/src/main/java/org/wso2/siddhi/core/query/selector/attribute/handler/avg/AvgOutputAttributeAggregatorDouble.java) class or a similar class inside the Siddhi code base to get a better understanding of the usage of `OutputAttributeAggregator` class.

A new instance of the output attribute aggregator is needed sometimes for internal workings of Siddhi. You just need to create a new instance of the class and return it in the `newInstance` method.